# Can't Deploy React Native to iPhone from Xcode 13 Beta 2 running on Virtual Machine running Big Sur 11.4

Tags: react-native-ios, ios14, macos-big-sur, vmware-fusion, xcode13

I have a Mac running Catalina with Xcode 12. This month, my iPhone upgraded to iOS 14.6, which requires Xcode 13. Xcode 13 requires Big Sur. Unfortunately, I don't have the money right now to upgrade my Mac to one with the hardware the Big Sur requires.

I installed VMWare Fusion 12 on this Mac and created a Virtual Machine running MacOS Big Sur 11.4. Then I installed Xcode 13 Beta 2, installed its dependencies, added the provisioning profile required to deploy, and selected my iPhone in Xcode as the target. When I build and attempt to deploy to the device, there are no errors, though it hangs/stalls right near the end of the process, around the time that Xcode says: "Preparing Editor Functionality". MetroBundler starts correctly and I see no issues in Terminal, Console, or Xcode. It just stops compiling/deploying.

I'm not super savvy when it comes to Xcode or the deployment process. I was hoping someone might be able to give me some tips as to how to figure out what's preventing the app from deploying to the device. Does Xcode have logs somewhere (other than Device Logs) that might help inform what's hanging?

Thank you for your time and I'm happy to provide screenshots or further information upon your suggestions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Xcode 13.3.1. Sounds like this issue: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690593